# class declarations and namespaces in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

What are differences between:

```
namespace Ui
{
     class T;
}
class T
{
     //some content
};
```

and

```
namespace Ui
{
     class T 
     {
          //some content
     };
}
```

I use Qt Creator and the first construction is used in the default code which is generated for Qt Gui Application. In the example project I have two classes: **class MyDialog : public QDialog** and **class MainWindow : public QMainWindow** Each of them contains in the private section a pointer to the class:

```
class T: public Q
{
private:
          Ui::T *pointer;
}
```

What is purpose of such contruction ?
When MainWindow class contains also a pointer to the MyDialog class then that pointer can't contain **Ui::** qualifier:

```
private:
          Ui::MainWindow *ui;
          MyDialog *mDialog;
```

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, I didn't noticed this fact before, maybe because usually prefer building Ui objects by code.

Anyway, the construct is used to avoid the generation of 'service' class names: for instance, from an actual .h of mine

```
namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
}
```

Note the `Ui::Dialog *ui;`: that's the actual class that's forwarded by the top declaration (that inside the namespace Ui). So QtCreator avoid to build an arbitrary symbol.

A nice trick, I think.

That forwarded class hides the gory details required by runtime construction of the GUI: you'll find in your build directory a .h (in my case, a ui_dialog.h) containing, for instance

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Dialog
{
public:
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QTabWidget *tabWidget;
...
};

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog: public Ui_Dialog {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

Answer (score 1):

namespaces are there to protect your code from aliasing classes, if you wrap your class in a namespace you can only access it through the use of that namespace, thus "class t" is not the same as "namespace::class t"